# Basic OO with PHP

Tags: php, namespaces

without telling me to buy a book, would anyone be interested in answering the following question?

if i am in a namespace with a class named foo. and i wanted to build another class called bar. how would i proceed to make foo, aware of bar and vice versa? at what cost? keep in mind that there could potentially be a whole microcosm of useful classes

Comment: foo class aware of bar class or an instance of foo aware of an instance of bar?

Comment: Isn't this question about PHP namespaces, rather than about OOP?

Comment: stefano: both =)
xtofl: as well

Answer (score 4):

No book, but [see the namespace documentation](http://php.net/manual/de/language.namespaces.php)

If your classes are in different namespaces:

```
<?php
namespace MyProject;

class Bar { /* ... */ }

namespace AnotherProject;

class Foo{ /* ... */ 
   function test() {
      $x = new \MyProject\Bar();
   }
}
?>
```

If the classes are in the same namespace, it's like no namespace at all.

Comment: The cruel and *ugly* truth :/

Comment: @Filip: That's the downvote? pffff; nice. The answer the this question was obviously answered by the manual. Ok, 'RTFM' isn't that polite.

Comment: Yes, that is the downvote, being mean and using language like that should be punished somehow.

Comment: >> If the classes are in the same namespace, it's like no namespace at all.

absolutely true. however the down vote comes from the fact that i'm not really interested in the namespace, per se. touchy touchy.

Comment: @Mike: revisit your question tags! (php, namespaces) and your question did not clarify WHERE your classes were. So I kindly answered the question for all "namespace cases". Very kind of you to to a downvote...

Answer (score 2):

About the namespace question, I refer to [tuergeist's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/98525/tuergeist).  The OOP aspect, I can only tell that this proposed mutual awareness of `Foo` and `Bar` has a slight smell about it.  You would rather work with interfaces and let implementation classes have references to the interface.  It might be this is called ['dependency inversion'](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_inversion_principle).

```
interface IFoo {
    function someFooMethod();
}

interface IBar {
    function someBarMethod();
}

class FooImpl1 {
    IBar $myBar;
    function someImpl1SpecificMethod(){
       $this->myBar->someBarMethod();
    }

    function someFooMethod() { // implementation of IFoo interface
       return "foostuff";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use other classes from other namespaces with the using statement. The following example implements a couple core class into your namespace:

```
namspace TEST
{
    using \ArrayObject, \ArrayIterator; // can now use by calling either without the slash
    class Foo
    {
        function __construct( ArrayObject $options ) // notice no slash
        {
            //do stuff
        }
    }
}
```